# http POST data from c client, blocking by csrf django

Tags: python, django, http, post

i need to update the database of django server from c client (not browser), i used POST method to update ,header body contain json data, since i sont have csrf token its giving back 403 error

im using middleware to acquire this json data (using `request.body`)  and save to database

my http header:

> "POST /post HTTP/1.1 \r\nHost:192.168.1.9\r\n\r\n {\"Lupttime\":\"7-2-2016 17:28\"}"

```
POST
Host:192.168.1.9

{"Lupttime":"7-2-2016 17:28"}
```

django log:

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /post
[09/Mar/2016 12:16:15] "POST /post HTTP/1.1 " 403 2629
```

additional doubt

- how do i update django server database directly not from browser/form
- i can get data like this easily GET post/?data={x:y} , but i read somewhere updating  server database with GET method is not good idea
- is it a good idea to send data in http header body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the decorator

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    #handle request
```

read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/)

Hope it helps.